# How to increase height when it's textwrap in textBox windowsphone8

Tags: windows-phone-8

How to increase height when it's textwrap.

```
  private void creattextbox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
               {
                    var txt = new TextBox();
                    txt.Height = 90;
                    txt.Width = 470;
                    txt.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
                    GR_Img.Children.Add(txt);
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear which height you referred. If it is height of the TextBox that you want to increase when text wrapping, then avoid hardcoding `Height` property. Remove this line :

```
txt.Height = 90;
```

But if you meant to increase height of each text line, in other words increasing space between lines of TextBox's `Text`, then simply set `LineHeight` property to desired value :

```
txt.LineHeight= 50;
```